# Remover atributo disabled quando uma condição for satisfeita

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, localstorage, javascript-eventos

Boa noite.

Estou tentando fazer uma tela de registro e login para uma aplicação que vai salvar os dados em `localStorage`. Para evitar que o usuário se cadastre com dados incompletos desabilitei o botão de submit usando `disabled`.

Minha intenção é quando todos os campos forem preenchidos a propriedade `disabled` seja removida e o botão possa ser clicado mas não consigo remover o `disabled`, tentei de várias maneiras e nada. Creio que a maneira mais fácil seria essa:

```js
var operacao = "A"; //"A"=Adição; "E"=Edição
var indice_selecionado = -1; //Índice do item selecionado na lista
var tbUsuarios;

//aqui o botão submit já está desabilitado
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonSubmitRegister').prop('disabled', true);
});

$(function () {
    tbUsuarios = localStorage.getItem("tbUsuarios");// Recupera os dados armazenados
    tbUsuarios = JSON.parse(tbUsuarios); // Converte string para objeto
    if (tbUsuarios === null) // Caso não haja conteúdo, iniciamos um vetor vazio
        tbUsuarios = [];
});

function Adicionar() {
    var usuario = JSON.stringify({
        Nome: $("#txtNome").val(),
        email: $("#txtEmail").val(),
        Senha: $("#txtSenha").val()
    });
    //aqui tentei remover o disabled quando os campos forem preenchidos
    if ($("#txtNome").val().length > 1 && $("#txtEmail").val().length > 1 && $("#txtSenha").val().length > 1){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#buttonSubmitRegister').prop('disabled', false);
        });
        tbUsuarios.push(usuario);
        localStorage.setItem("tbUsuarios", JSON.stringify(tbUsuarios));
        alert("Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="formRegister" nome="formRegister" class="positionFormRegister">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                    <label for="txtNome"></label>
                    <input id="txtNome" name="txtNome" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Crie seu nome de Usuário" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                    <label for="txtEmail"></label>
                    <input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Seu endereço de e-mail" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                    <label for="txtSenha"></label>
                    <input id="txtSenha" name="txtSenha" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Crie sua senha" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <!--Botão Submit-->
                <div>
                    <input id="buttonSubmitRegister" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg positionFormRegister" value="Cadastrar no e-Pro &raquo;" onclick="Adicionar()">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver?
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Eu tentei também com  ' $("#txtNome").val().length != " " '. Mas não deu certo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você quer que quando o campo tenha o numero de caracteres corretos, ele seja habilitado novamente certo? Note que o `$(document).keyup(function(){});` vai fazer a verificação sempre que uma tecla for pressionada. Meu código exemplo:

```
$(document).keyup(function() {
    if($("#email-test").val().length > 0 && $("#password-test").val().length > 0) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit-test').prop('disabled', false);
        });
    }
});
```

Exemplo no jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Knautiluz/L9vqatoh/2/

Tente assim com o evento fora da função adicionar, do contrário ele só vai ser computado quando a função for acionada:

```js
var operacao = "A"; //"A"=Adição; "E"=Edição
var indice_selecionado = -1; //Índice do item selecionado na lista
var tbUsuarios;

//aqui o botão submit já está desabilitado
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#buttonSubmitRegister').prop('disabled', true);
});

$(function() {
  tbUsuarios = localStorage.getItem("tbUsuarios"); // Recupera os dados armazenados
  tbUsuarios = JSON.parse(tbUsuarios); // Converte string para objeto
  if (tbUsuarios === null) // Caso não haja conteúdo, iniciamos um vetor vazio
    tbUsuarios = [];
});

function Adicionar() {
  var usuario = JSON.stringify({
    Nome: $("#txtNome").val(),
    email: $("#txtEmail").val(),
    Senha: $("#txtSenha").val()
  });
}



$(document).keyup(function() {
  // habilita caso o numero de caracteres seja maior que 1.
  if ($("#txtNome").val().length > 1 && $("#txtEmail").val().length > 1 && $("#txtSenha").val().length > 1) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#buttonSubmitRegister').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    tbUsuarios.push(usuario);
    localStorage.setItem("tbUsuarios", JSON.stringify(tbUsuarios));
    alert("Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!");
    return true;
  }
  // desabilita o campo o valor seja apagado.
  if ($("#txtNome").val().length < 1 && $("#txtEmail").val().length < 1 && $("#txtSenha").val().length < 1) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#buttonSubmitRegister').prop('disabled', true);
    });
  }
});
```

Não sei exatamente qual as suas necessidades, mas essa verificação pode ser facilmente removida pelo usuário, claro que vai diminuir altamente o número que cadastros feitos faltando algum dado... mas caso seja um usuário malicioso ele pode manipular isso, então é bom que exista uma verificação no **lado do servidor** também. Como você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação que usa o `localStorage` não sei se há muito que possa ser feito. Mas dou essa dica também caso no futuro alguém encontre isso e esteja desenvolvendo algo em `PHP` por exemplo, e ache que simplesmente isso vai resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Não adianta modificar o valor do atributo `disabled` para falso.

Os navegadores não lêem o valor do atributo. Eles apenas consideram sua presença. Se o atributo existe, o elemento que o tem está desabilitado. Se o atributo não existe, o elemento não está desabilitado.

Portanto, as quatro formas abaixo são equivalentes:

```
<input type="button" disabled>
<input type="button" disabled="true">
<input type="button" disabled="false">
<input type="button" disabled="Fui na Espanha buscar o meu chapéu, azul e branco da cor daquele céu"> <!--Ou qualquer outra canção de sua preferência-->
```

A única forma de reabilitar o seu botão é removendo o atributo. Você pode utilizar a função [`removeProp` do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) para isso. E.g.:

```
$("#buttonSubmitRegister").removeProp("disabled");
```

Se algum dia você encontrar um navegador que habilite um elemento que esteja com o valor do atributo `disabled` igual a `false`, saiba que esse navegador não segue a especificação do HTML 5:

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

"A presença de um atributo booleano em um elemento representa o valor verdadeiro e a ausência do atributo representa o valor falso".

Fonte: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute

Comment: A idéia é boa, mas tem isso:   "Also note that the .removeProp() method should not be used to set these properties to false. Once a native property is removed, it cannot be added again. See .removeProp() for more information. "

Comment: Interessante essa, mas vendo por esse lado, nenhum dos meus navegadores incluindo o Chrome e Firefox que estão atualizados seguem essa regra, o unico desatualizado é o IE, e nele também funciona.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi desse trecho, qualquer valor dentro do `disabled` altera a condição para verdadeira, na ausência é `false` ou seja `$("#elemento").prop('disabled', "");` também voltaria a habilitar o elemento. Não seria necessário então o `removeProp("disabled")` correto?